# ADMM for Linear Program over graph

Tags: linear-programming, admm

I want to use ADMM to solve a LP defined over a graph.
According to

> Distributed optimization and statistical learning via the alternating direction method of multipliers
>   S. Boyd, N. Parikh, E. Chu, B. Peleato, and J. Eckstein, 2011

the first primal update ($x^{k+1}$) is given by the solution of

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \rho I & A' \\ A & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} x^{k+1} \\ \nu \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} q - \rho(z^k - u^k) \\ -b \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

Thus, to solve it for $x^{k+1}$ one has to invert the matrix and therefore needs the full vectors $z^k$ and $u^k$.

Because my A is (almost) the incidence matrix, I would like to compute $x^{k+1}_i$ only as a function of $z^k_j$ and $u^k_j$, for $j$ such that $A_{ij} \neq 0$ (in this way, hypothetically, nodes' graph needs fewer communications).

Is there a direct way to do so?